# Obscurus messing with sprites to hide hats behind Emperor

Tags: discussion, feature-request, winter-bash, profile-picture

**We all know the story of the Emperor's new cloths.**

Now, is the view the same from here as from there? Last year we could resize and place the hats on any part of our avatar, this year, they're tucked behind that layer.

[image: Just a newb's avatar to illustrate.]

Image courtesy of JustANewb.

Is that just me? (Am I the unicorn, who's the unicorn, is there a unicorn, what's a unicorn?)

**My requested feature is that the hat layer be moved to the front to save all that screen capturing, copying pasting shenanigans needed to place the hat over the Emperor's
(in)dignity.**

Brave: 1.33.106 Chromium: 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I don't know if it's only you. But it's definitely not me (and not anyone else posting their hats). What browser?

Comment: Also unable to reproduce this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/otdf5.png, voting to close as such.

Comment: Oh, fair enough, just tried this in Chrome and no repro. First Brave-related glitch I've seen. @YaakovEllis